# PDFRenderer showing wrong PDF

Tags: android, android-studio, android-assets, pdfrenderer

I'm having problems with `PDFRenderer` not changing the PDF it shows after the first run of the application, no matter what I do.

I'm using the code from the official PDFRenderer Sample from https://developer.android.com/samples/PdfRendererBasic/project.html and Android Studio.

Exact steps I take which can be used to replicate this:

1. Add 2 files to `Application/src/main/assets`: `PDF_1.pdf` and `PDF_2.pdf`
2. In `PdfRendererBasicFragment.java`, line 140 in function openRenderer, change

   ```
   mFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd("sample.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();
   ```

   to

   ```
   mFileDescriptor = context.getAssets().openFd("PDF_1.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();
   ```
3. Run project; Everything works as expected
4. In code above, change `"PDF_1.pdf"` to `"PDF_2.pdf"`
5. Run project again; The application still shows PDF_1.pdf

I have tried starting a completely new emulator, removing PDF_1.pdf from assets folder, syncronizing assets and "clean / rebuild project" in Android Studio , but it still keeps displaying PDF_1.pdf after the first run.

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Thank you; Using exact sample code from here https://developer.android.com/samples/PdfRendererBasic/src/com.example.android.pdfrendererbasic/PdfRendererBasicFragment.html

Comment: Are you shure that your first and second file are different?